# Laravel 4 : Authentication when having a many to many relationship

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4, many-to-many

I have a users, roles and role_users table. In the roles table I have a user and admin value. Now I want to be able to edit users when the role of a user is admin. I don't know how to access the role_name == 'admin' in laravel.

When I use this it works :

```
 @if(Auth::user()->user_username == 'Gilko')
```

But I want to be able to access this `role_name == 'admin'`

role_users migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_users', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('role_user_id');
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        });

        Schema::table('role_users', function($table)
        {
            $table->foreign('role_id')
                ->references('role_id')->on('roles');
            //->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('user_id')->on('users');
            //->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

User model :

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface  {

   protected $table = 'users';

   protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

   protected $hidden = ["password"];

   public function getAuthIdentifier()
   {
       return $this->getKey();
   }

   public function getAuthPassword()
   {
       return $this->user_password;
   }

   public function getReminderEmail()
   {
       return $this->email;
   }

   public function user()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('Checklist', 'user_id', 'user_id');
   }

   public function roles(){
       return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'role_users', 'user_id', 'role_id');
   }

   public function getRememberToken()
   {
       //return $this->remember_token;
   }

   public function setRememberToken($value)
   {
       //$this->remember_token = $value;
   }

   public function getRememberTokenName()
   {
       //return 'remember_token';
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `role` relationship defined in your `user` model?

Comment: It is a many to many relationship, so it stores the user_id and role_id in a table called role_users. I edited my question with the role_users migration.

Comment: Please include the user model file as well.

Comment: User model included.

Comment: So you want to see if the user has a `role` with `name=='admin'`?

Comment: Yes that is what I want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a function which checks for this on your user model...

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return (bool)$this->roles()->where('name', 'admin')->count();
}
```

And then you can easily use it with...

```
@if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
if (Auth::user()->roles()->where('name', 'admin')->first())
```

`first` will return null if there's no result.

You can also use `firstOrFail`: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

```
try (Auth::user()->roles()->where('name', 'admin')->firstOrFail()) {
    // User has admin role
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    // User doesn't have admin role
}
```

**Edit** Just realized I had a brain fart. Corrected the code :-)